# springboot application empty method response time , request per second

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance, kubernetes

I have a springboot application hosted on kubernetes environment, and there is an empty method which return 200 OK
i need to improve the request per second. Currently, the configuration parameters which i tired are as follows:

**1 pod --> (RPS=55)**

```
6 CPU and 5 GB memory
server.tomcat.accept-count=1000
server.tomcat.max-connections=20000
server.tomcat.max-threads=2000
```

**4 pod --> (RPS=55)**

```
6 CPU and 5 GB memory (distributed equally)
server.tomcat.accept-count=1000
server.tomcat.max-connections=20000
server.tomcat.max-threads=2000
```

**4 pod --> (RPS=180)**

```
20 CPU and 5 GB memory (distributed equally)
server.tomcat.accept-count=1000
server.tomcat.max-connections=20000
server.tomcat.max-threads=2000
```

**4 pod --> (RPS=180)**

```
20 CPU and 5 GB memory (distributed equally)
server.tomcat.accept-count=5000
server.tomcat.max-connections=40000
server.tomcat.max-threads=5000
```

i assume **20 CPU** should process more request per second but despite increasing above parameters still the RPS do not increase.
Is there any other way how we can improve this, its possible i am missing out some thing.

Comment: How do you test this?

Comment: tested via load testing tool